# Probability_question2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

There are N people in a room,  each wearing a different hat.  They all take their hats off,put them together and then each randomly picks one up.  What is the probability of no persongetting  their  own  hat  back  (denote  this  event  by  A)?  What  does  this  probability  become  as N→∞?

Comment: I solved it using permutations,but I'd like to solve it using probability. Any idea?

Comment: Familiar with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)? IMV permutations and probability are quite hard to separate.